# JavaScript Not able to set focus to first li element within ul

Tags: javascript, html

I have below code:

```
<ul id='someId'>
 <li class='someClass'>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I want to set focus on first li element within ul based on some condition.

My first attempt is like this:

```
var ul = document.getElementById('someId');           
var child = ul.childNodes[0];
child.focus();
```

My second attempt is like this :

```
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('someClass');
var aNode = y[0];
aNode.focus();
```

But none of the above works

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the HTML, please?

Comment: The HTMLElement.focus() method sets focus on the specified element, if it can be focused. Is it focusable? How do you know that it did not focus?

Comment: I used document.activeElement to check which is active element after focus

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is that you can't focus a non input element without setting tabIndex.

```
<li tabIndex="-1">...</li>
```

You can Try this fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vevzxLzk)

Comment: Reply from [Matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1949411/matt): _"But `tabindex=-1` means NOT focusable per the spec. Also, even if you fix it to `tabindex=0`, you get no visual indication that the focus is there in some browsers so you need to style it."_ (Not enough reputation to comment)

Answer (score 0):

An 'li' can't have focus, however an 'input' can, so you write yourself the following script:

```
function installLI(obj){
       var ul = document.createElement('ul');
       obj.appendChild(ul);
       var li = document.createElement('li');
       var txt = document.createElement('input');
       li.appendChild(txt);
       ul.appendChild(li);
       txt.focus();
       li.removeChild(txt);
}
```

Where 'obj' is the object (like an editable div) that you're appending your list to.