# How to focus on a list item with useRef react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a dynamically generated array of list items

```
const  ArtistProfile = props => {
  // api data
  const tracks = props.data.artistTopTracks && props.data.artistTopTracks.tracks
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState(null)
  const songRef = useRef(null)
  // effect hook that creates list of SongListItem components
  useEffect(() => {
    if (tracks) {
      const trackTags = tracks.map((track, index) => {
        if (index > 4) return 
        return (
          <SongListItem ref={songRef} role="button" key={track.id} onClick={() => songRef.current.focus()}>
            <SongTag
              image={track.album.images[1].url}
              duration={msToTime(track.duration_ms)}
              name={track.name}
              explicit={track.explicit}
            />
          </SongListItem>
        )
      })
      setSongs(trackTags)
    }
  }, [tracks])
  return (
    <ArtistProfileContainer>
      <ul>{songs}</ul>
    </ArtistProfileContainer>
  )
}
```

Im trying to use the `onClick` event to focus on one item in the list. All my list items are passed this ref `const songRef = useRef(null)` and I'm using the `songRef.current` property to focus on the element I'm clicking on. This isn't focusing on anything when clicking so none of my styles are changing.

```
const SongListItem = styled.li`
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  :focus {
    svg {
      opacity: 0.7;
    }
    background-color: #181818;
  }
`
```

I'm trying to achieve the same results you can see on this Spotify link https://open.spotify.com/artist/5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x

If you hover over the "Popular" songs you see the styles change temporarily, but once you click it keeps the changes until you click another song.

Answer (score 1):

You just can't focus on li:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30213871/7763883

Add

```
<li tabIndex="-1" ...
```

And it will work.

There are tabIndex's in your example.

Comment: This allows me to focus but it always focuses on the last item in the list. I need it to focus depending on the item I click on. So at this point I think i'm using refs incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, ref is a pointer to a DOMNode. So one

```const songRef = useRef(null)```

will only create a pointer to one node.