# Style not getting applied when `focusout` happens due to `shift+tab`

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a very simple scenario in which I want to show the submenu associated with `li` when it's focused via tab key and when the focus is out, it should hide the submenu.

Here's my code:

```
       const listener = (e) => {
          submenu.style.visibility = 'visible';
          submenu.style.opacity = 1;
        };

        element.addEventListener('focus', listener);
```

And for `focusout`:

```
       if(submenu.matches(':focus-within:not(:focus)') === false){
         console.log('helloo')
         submenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
         submenu.style.opacity = 0;
       }
     });
```

The code works perfectly if you press tabs and move out of the submenu elements.
However if you press `shift+tab` and go to the particular `li`, it actually shows the submenu item, however when you're out of the focus, it doesn't hide as if, the following code has no effect:

```
submenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
           submenu.style.opacity = 0;
```

which is written inside `focusout` block.

I'm sure the code inside gets executed, for if I write something like this,
`submenu.style.backgroundColor = 'red';`
it actually does that.

So I'm missing something obvious and appreciate any help. Thanks

Here's the snippet:

```js
const navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-header-button]');

navButtons.forEach((element) => {
  const closestListElement = element.closest('li');
  const [submenu] =
  closestListElement.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-nav__list');

  if (!submenu) {
    return;
  }

  const listener = (e) => {
    submenu.style.visibility = 'visible';
    submenu.style.opacity = 1;
  };

  element.addEventListener('focus', listener);

  submenu.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
    if (submenu.matches(':focus-within:not(:focus)') === false) {
      submenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      submenu.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      submenu.style.opacity = 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.c-header__navigation-desktop ul {
  display: none;
}

.c-header__navigation-desktop:focus-within ul {
  display: list-item;
}
```

```html
<ul class="c-header__navigation c-header__navigation-desktop" data-header-link-widget="">
  <li data-header-li="" class="c-header__navigation-item dropdown-nav">
    <a data-header-button="" class="c-header__link  " href="https://demo332.jibeapply.com/internal/jobs">Search Jobs</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-nav__list">
      <li class="dropdown-nav__item">
        <a data-header-button="" class="nested-link  " href="k">some link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown-nav__item">
        <a data-header-button="" class="nested-link  " href="o">some link 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-header-li="" class="c-header__navigation-item ">
    <a data-header-button="" class="c-header__link  " href="">Departments</a>
  </li>
  <li data-header-li="" class="c-header__navigation-item ">
    <a data-header-button="" class="c-header__link  " href="https://demo332.jibeapply.com/internal/jobs?view=personalization">Benefits</a>
  </li>
  <li data-header-li="" class="c-header__navigation-item ">
    <a data-header-button="" class="c-header__link  " href="">Internships</a>
  </li>
  <li data-header-li="" class="c-header__navigation-item ">
    <a data-header-button="" class="c-header__link  " href="">Diversity and Inclusion</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A working snippet and some HTML might go a long way to getting optimal answers here

Comment: Due to the lack of HTML  and/or CSS unless that is added this is a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/30213871/125981  Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus and closely related is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Hmm, makes sense. Let me quickly add some snippets.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Added the snippet. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Perhaps also take time to format and remove unneeded white space.  Click that Tidy feature on the snippet :)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Will do that. But are you able to run the snippet and understand the issue btw?

Comment: The problem is in that you are reacting to the `focusout` event on your submenu `ul` there. When you have the focus on that `some link 1` link, and shift-tab, the `Search Jobs` link now gets focus. That fires your event handler, but because of the condition you implemented, nothing happens. Now you shift-tab again, the focus moves from `Search Jobs` further up. But this does now not fire the `focusout` event on your submenu any more - because the submenu did already _not have_ the focus any more, before you tabbed.

Comment: @CBroe Try shift + tab just when the focus is on `some link 1` and you'll notice, the focus moves to `Search Jobs`. However, the code to hide the visibility has no effect even though you'll see the `background color` changes and even if you put a console.log in `focusout` listener block, it will print out.

Comment: _"the code to hide the visibility has no effect even though you'll see the background color changes"_ - the visibility change _does_ have an effect, only you _undo_ that effect right away again. You just put the focus back on `Search Jobs` - and that now fires your `listener` function again, in which you are doing what ...? Exactly, you are making your submenu visible again.

Comment: @CBroe Ah, got that. That's silly of me. What's the simplest way you can suggest to resolve this? Do I need to go for another approach altogthe?

Comment: Probably to check what the `relatedTarget` of the `focus` event is, that is the element that is _losing_ the focus. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FocusEvent/relatedTarget

Comment: hmm the way I implemented was adding some CSS to it:
```
.c-header__navigation-desktop ul {
  display: none;
}

.c-header__navigation-desktop:focus-within ul {
  display: list-item;
}
```
Thanks

Comment: I added that CSS to the snippet; please update if what I did does not match your setup.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler and more reliable approach to achieve your desired behavior could involve using the mouseenter and mouseleave events along with the focus and blur events for keyboard navigation.

```
const navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-header-button]');

const showSubmenu = (submenu) => {
submenu.style.visibility = 'visible';
submenu.style.opacity = 1;
};

const hideSubmenu = (submenu) => {
submenu.style.visibility = 'hidden';
submenu.style.opacity = 0;
};

navButtons.forEach((element) => {
const closestListElement = element.closest('li');
const submenu = closestListElement.querySelector('.dropdown-nav__list');

if (submenu) {
    element.addEventListener('focus', () => showSubmenu(submenu));
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => showSubmenu(submenu));
    
    submenu.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => hideSubmenu(submenu));
    submenu.addEventListener('blur', () => hideSubmenu(submenu));
}
});
```